# Set cors headers in Laravel but still receiving error

Tags: laravel, cors

I set Cors headers in Laravel but still receiving error. For debugging purposes, I set it directly in public/index.php instead of in the middleware. I can see the headers is there, but still got an error.

[image]

Make it more confusing, whenever I set it on public/index.php for debugging, it gives me the second error. But, whenever I comment it out, which means no headers at all, it gives me the first error. Why?

This is what I set in public/index.php for debugging:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* ');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
```

Comment: Can you share your `cors.php`

Comment: I don't have for this one

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
=================================================
step 1 : install package
=================================================
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors

=================================================
step 2 : config/app.php -> destination
=================================================

Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,

=================================================
step 3 : app/Http/Kernel.php -> destination
=================================================
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];

=================================================
step 4 : Vendor publish
=================================================

php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"
```